# creating queues on the fly

Tags: mapreduce, queue, hdp

I want to run X number of MR jobs in a loop with each one getting submitted to a random queue which created on the fly.

Example:  -D mapred.queuename=root.random name.

I want to loop through this as many times as needed and it should create as many queues in YARN on-the-fly.

Is there a way to do this?